# Need URI list in marklogic database using Xquery

Tags: xquery, marklogic, marklogic-8

After executing the below xquery, resulted in whole content from XML but my objective is to get the list of URI.

```
let $i := cts:search(//root,
    cts:element-value-query(
        xs:QName("no"),
        "123")) 

return ($i)
```

Comment: Please provide a reproducible example, which necessarily includes example input here.

Comment: Have you looked at `fn:document-uri` [Documentation](https://docs.marklogic.com/fn:document-uri)

Comment: @JensErat i.e.) I have 20 files in marklogic db the above xquery matches 10 files and provides the matched content  but what I want is the matched files URI. is this possible or am I not clear.

Comment: see also: [`cts:uris()`](http://docs.marklogic.com/cts:uris)

Comment: @Antony no, this is/was not clear at all. The input could also have contained URIs (that's what I understood the first time reading your question) ... This is a very relevant part of information that should explicitly be listed in the question, also that the content actually spans multiple files, while your query matches only some of them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If all you want is the URI, use [`cts:uris()`](http://docs.marklogic.com/cts:uris). The 3rd parameter lets you define a query that will filter the URIs list.

So with your example this would work:

```
cts:uris(
  (), 
  (), 
  cts:element-value-query(
          xs:QName("no"),
          "123")
)
```